# linux process group example

Tags: linux, process

What a process group is, has been already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548823/use-and-meaning-of-session-and-process-group-in-unix):

> A process group is a collection of related processes which can all be signalled at once.

Unfortunately there's no real world example of how and when you start a "a collection of related processes which can all be signalled at once".

Could anyone here give me some code example of where he's starting a process group and killing all the processes inside with `kill -- -0`?

For example would the apache webserver with it's children be a process group where when the main process is killed the rest of the PIDs within the process group are killed too?

Answer (score 2):

There are many real world examples; `some_app` from the linked question could be `ls` or `cat` or the more complicated example

```
$ ps axo ppid,pid,pgid,command | grep $$
41613  2926  2926 mksh -l
 2926 14131 14131 ps axo ppid,pid,pgid,command
 2926 14132 14131 grep 2926
$
```

which shows that the shell (`mksh`) has started a new process group (`14131`) that has members `14131` and `14132`. These could be signalled if not for the fact they do not linger around; for that you need a `sleep` or some form of blocking

```
$ perl -e 'warn $$; sleep 999' | perl -ne 'sleep 999'
14148 at -e line 1.
```

and then elsewhere you can run `kill -- -14148` to kill that group.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. One learns best in practice, not in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$ ( sleep 100 & sleep 100 & sleep 100 & )
$ ps -Ao pid,pgid,command | grep sleep
19734 19733 sleep 100
19735 19733 sleep 100
19736 19733 sleep 100
19789 19788 grep sleep
```

`()` creates a new subshell (at least in Bash), which will be the process group leader of all of the processes started (IOW: shell will create a new subshell, which PID will be the PGID of all three sleeps, which will be executed asynchronously in the background).

To kill those sleeps one can just type `kill -19733`.

Another example:

```
$ cat script1.sh 
sleep 100 &
./script2.sh

$ cat script2.sh 
sleep 100 &

$ ./script1.sh 
$ ps -Ao pid,pgid,command | grep sleep
21605 21604 sleep 100
21607 21604 sleep 100
21618 21617 grep sleep
```

or `sleep 10 | sleep 20 | sleep 30 | sleep 40 &` will also share the same PGID.